# Find the limit of function in $R^n$

Tags: calculus

a) $$\lim\limits_{(x,y,z) \to (0,0,0)} \frac {xyz}{x^2+y^2 +z^2}$$

b) $$\lim\limits_{(x,y,z) \to (0,0,0)} \frac {xyz}{x^3+y^3 +z^3}$$

For b) I belive that the limit doesn't exist be cause let $a_k =(1/k,1/k,1/k)$ and $b_k =(1/k,2/k,2/k)$ we have

$f(a_k)=1/3$ and $f(b_k)=2/9$ thus the limit doesn't exist. Am I correct?

For part a), I can do the same way to show that the limit doesn't exist. However, I don't think the professor just gave me 2 non exists limit and ask to find the limit. I feel like I did some thing wrong, but I don't know where is the mistake.

Comment: The argument for (b) is correct, but $f(b_k)=4/17$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the inequalities $$0 \le \frac {|xyz|}{x^2+y^2+z^2} \le |x| \frac {y^2+z^2}{2(x^2+y^2+z^2)} \le \frac {|x|} 2 $$ and the sqweeze theorem, one obtains the answer $0$ in the case a).